# SQL error - Has more columns than were specified in the column list; left join a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select
    ARTH.ARCo, ARTH2.LastPayment
from
    ARTH
left join
    (select 
         ARCo, Customer, 
         max(case when ARTransType = 'P' then TransDate end) LastPayment
     from 
         ARTH
     where 
         TransDate <= '2022-03-31'
     group by 
         ARCo, Customer) ARTH2 (NOLOCK) on (ARTH.ARCo = ARTH2.ARCo and ARTH.Customer = ARTH2.Customer)
```

As you can see, I am trying to left join a subquery. I keep getting an error

> ARTH2 has more columns than were specified in the column list

Somehow the query will work if I remove NOLOCK. Can someone explain what the error message means? Is removing NOLOCK the only way to make the query work?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: You can't put a NOLOCK hint there (and arguably shouldn't have one anywhere). You need to either remove it altogether or put it on ARTH inside the subquery, but then it doesn't make sense to allow read uncommitted on the subquery but not on the same table on the outer query. Peppering hints on table names - even when you need them - is just a bad way to do it, but [especially with NOLOCK](https://sqlblog.org/nolock). Usually much better to set isolation level at session scope.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for the response. Can you elaborate a bit more on "Usually much better to set isolation level at session scope"?

Comment: @lucylucy One obvious example is the logical mistake of attempting to apply the NOLOCK hint to arth2 derived table - which merely selects rows from the same table as the that used by the outer query. Read the link! In general, you should avoid using hints without having identified a ** real need** to do so and without understanding the consequences of their use. In addition, stop throwing parentheses throughout your code for no effective purpose. That just makes your code more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I am still learning SQL. Lesson learnt is to be cautious with NOLOCK.

Answer (score 0):

The NOLOCK hint can come after the table name, ***if you need it***, but not after the alias of the sub-query.
Most of the time there is no need of NOLOCK but the question does not give us the information and circumstances needed to advise as to this.

```
select
    ARTH.ARCo,
    ARTH2.LastPayment
from
    ARTH
left join
    (select 
         ARCo, Customer, 
         max(case when ARTransType = 'P' then TransDate end) LastPayment
     from 
         ARTH WITH (NOLOCK)
     where 
         TransDate <= '2022-03-31'
     group by 
         ARCo, Customer) ARTH2
 on (ARTH.ARCo = ARTH2.ARCo 
         and ARTH.Customer = ARTH2.Customer);
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1afd785449f203fc82be1ddd7baff1d4